# How to jump to screen if an action fails?

Tags: install4j

I have added actions in "Installation Screens" to install. In a "Run Script" if some condition fails i want to jump to some other screen . I tried using :

context.gotoScreen(context.getScreenById("ID"));

but this doesnt happen immediately (as given in documentation) .It first executes all the remaining actions and then goes to the mentioned screen. But i want it not to execute the following actions and  immediately go to the mentioned screen. How can i do that?
Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all actions below the screen and choose "Create group from selection" from the context menu.

Then select the action group that was just created and select the "On error break group" property.